# Why isn't "type" in the MRO of "int"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

Based on my understanding, the second element of `int.mro()` should have been `<class 'type'>`, as that is the output of `int.__class__`. But instead `int.mro()` gives `[<class 'int'>, <class 'object'>]`. How is it implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the `int.mro()` shows you the inheritance tree for the `int` class, not the `type` metaclass which creates the `int` class, hence why `<class 'type'>` shouldn't be in `int.mro()`. When the metaclass creates the class object, it also builds the `__mro__`.

Conversely, `__class__` is a reference to the *type* of an instance, showing you the class to which a class instance belongs. In this case, the class to which `int` belongs is the metaclass `type`. It is for this reason that `x.__class__` is the same as `type(x)` for the majority of use cases.

You can see the relationship between them in the following examples:

```py
print(int.__class__)
> <class 'type'>

print(int.mro())
> [<class 'int'>, <class 'object'>]

print(int.__class__.__mro__)
> [<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>]

print(int().__class__)
> <class 'int'>
```

Furthermore, you can see this relationship in the most simple example of a class you can construct:

```py
class A:
    pass

obj = A()
   
print(A.mro())
> [<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]

print(A.__class__)
> <class 'type'>
```